# p5.js Instance Mode: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: object, push, processing, instance, p5.js

I have a sketch in global mode that works perfectly, and I'm now bringing it into another document in Instance mode as it's sitting alongside a 3D/WEBGL sketch.

Whenever I click to push a new instance of Pulse(), I get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in return coming from the for() loop in draw(). As I said it works perfectly in global mode, so I must just have the syntax wrong here but I can't find any examples of using objects in p5 Instance Mode. I have no idea why it can't read from the array, or why it can't push.

I was very unsure of the syntax when pushing to an object array in p5.js Instance Mode. I have also tried variations of s.pulses.push(new s.Pulse()) and s.pulses.s.push(new s.Pulse()) but these returned pushing errors. The code below seems to be pushing but the array just can't be read.

Any help would be great, thank you.

```javascript
var twoDee = function(s) {
var cnv;
var cnvWidth, cnvHeight;
var pulsesAmount;
var pulses = [];

s.setup = function() {
    s.cnvWidth = s.windowWidth;
    s.cnvHeight = document.getElementById('sketch-wrap-bleed-bottom').offsetHeight;
    s.cnv = s.createCanvas(s.cnvWidth, s.cnvHeight, s.P2D);
    s.cnv.parent("sketch-wrap-bleed-bottom");
    s.pulsesAmount = 0;
}

s.draw = function() {
    s.background(40);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.pulsesAmount; i++) {
        s.pulses[i].move(); // problem here
        s.pulses[i].display();
    }

    s.noFill();
    s.stroke(255);
    s.ellipse(s.mouseX, s.mouseY, 30, 30);
}

s.Pulse = function() {
    this.size = 20;
    this.grow = 0.5;
    this.xPos = s.width/2 + 200;
    this.yPos = s.height/2;
    this.opacity = 255;

    this.move = function() {
        this.size += this.grow;
        this.opacity = map(this.size, 0, 60, 255, 0);
    }

    this.display = function() {
        s.noFill();
        s.strokeWeight(2);
        s.stroke(242, 202, 102, this.opacity);
        s.translate(this.xPos, this.yPos);
        s.ellipse(0, 0, this.size, this.size);
        s.translate(-this.xPos, -this.yPos);
    }
}

s.mousePressed = function() {
    s.pulsesAmount += 1;
    s.pulses = s.push(new s.Pulse());
}
```

}

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle or a codepen of your code? We can't run your code because it throws an error because it can't find the `sketch-wrap-bleed-bottom'` element.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I've made a codepen version but the console isn't printing out the error code. It's here anyway http://codepen.io/tomricci/pen/wzNPAK?editors=0001 I've added an ellipse on the mouse which cuts off as soon as you click to demonstrate that the sketch breaks as soon as you try to push an object

Comment: Safari phrases the error as "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the `s` variable for stuff that's coming from P5.js, like `mouseX` or the `setup()` function.

For stuff that you're declaring, like the `pulses` and `pulsesAmount` variables, you don't use the `s` variable. So your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pulsesAmount; i++) {
    pulses[i].move();
    pulses[i].display();
}
```

**Edit:** After you fixed that problem, you still have another problem. This line doesn't make sense:

```
pulses = s.push(new Pulse());
```

Please consult [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) to better understand what the `push()` function does. It has nothing to do with arrays.

You might be thinking of the `append()` function, but even then your syntax is off. You have to pass the array into the function along with the value you want to add to it. Like this:

```
s.append(pulses, new Pulse());
```

After you fix that you'll still have some other problems (like not using the `s` variable to get to the `map()` function), but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've gone through and tried to fix up the syntax according to this but I'm still getting the error. Is there something in here that I've treated incorrectly?

Comment: @themessup Please see my edited answer. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for a back and forth, so if you have a follow-up question, please post it as a new question in its own post and we'll go from there.